# input must be number format only check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script with simple math function. I want user to insert only numbers. How can I do it in the code? Or even better - how can I prevent the input of non-numeric characters?

```
 $('form').submit(
 function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    $('#result').text("Result is " + parseInt($('#var1').val()) / 2 + " days");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eWXUT/1/

Comment: `how can I prevent the input of non-numeric characters?` Don't do that, it's very annoying. Make your application tolerant rather than dictatorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the input thru this:

```
$('#var1').keypress(function(event) {
var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if (!(
        (code >= 48 && code <= 57) //numbers
        || (code == 46) //period
    )
    || (code == 46 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1)
   )
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or with jquery:

```
$('#val1').change(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().match(/\d*\.?\d+/));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing non-integer values on key press/up/down - here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/eWXUT/2/)

```
$('#var1').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(){
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/([^\d]+)/, '')); 
    });
```